# how to set input properly via viewchild in angular?

Tags: angular

Let say i have a parent component and a child component.

```
class ChildComponent {

   @input() id: number;


   public showIdFromOutside() {
      console.log(this.id)
   }
 }
```

Now I want to pass the id from the parent component to the child component. And I will access the function showIdFromOutside(). That is how my parent component look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <button (click)="displayId()"> click me</button>
    <child style="visibility=hidden"></child>
  `
})
    
class ParentComponent{
    
       @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) childComponent : ChildComponent ;
    
       userId=10;

       public displayId() {
          this.childComponent.id= this.userId;
          this.childComponent.showIdFromOutside()
       }
     }
```

However, After I have implemented this, I am having an error like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
```

Now how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try `console.log(id)` -> `console.log(this.id)`

Comment: still having the same error

Comment: @input() id: number;

Comment: Did you mean `@ViewChild` (with a capital `V`)?

Comment: i beg pardon. i have fixed the typo ,@meriton

Comment: I don't see the `ChildComponent` in the parent template.

Comment: Do you mean the import ChildComponent ? @ConnorsFan

Comment: No, something like `<child-component></child-component>` in the parent template. `ViewChild` will refer to it only if it is in the template.

Comment: i do not need to render the child-component inside the parent component. I just need to access the child component's function. so it's not needed in the above case. @ConnorsFan

Comment: If you don't need to render the child component, why is it a component? In order to refer to it, there has to be an instance somewhere. Maybe you want a service, or an ordinary class.

Comment: i need to render the child component in other cases. Just for a particular task, sometime u might just need to access the component function. In that case, you can create a reference of childcomponent via ViewChild. @ConnorsFan

Comment: `ViewChild` will not create an instance. It refers to an existing instance in the parent component (if there is such an instance, otherwise you get `undefined`). If you need the method without the child component, you may consider moving that method to a service.

Comment: you can also create a reference to your childComponent using ViewChild. @ConnorsFan

Comment: But you don't have an instance to refer to. So the reference is `undefined`.

Comment: in the above case, i have an instance called userID inside the parent component. I want to pass that userID to child-Component and print that out. I really don't get it where have I done wrong. Could you please elaborate. however, I appreciate your time. @ConnorsFan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parent component doesn't have your child component in html.

`@ViewChild` is only available for an element already rendered in the DOM.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <button (click)="displayId()"> click me</button>
    <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  `
})
```

Comment: After i have added the child component with visibility=hidden, I am having the same error

Comment: can you add your code with that `visibility=hidden`? i am not sure what is `visibility`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewchild-visibility - working demo here. you can add your code there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have not inserted child component in your parent component which means your parent component has not create an instance for your child component, that's why when you query child component through `ViewChild`, it's 'undefined'. Put it a simple way, your `parent component` and `child component` do not have any connection. They are not `parent` and `Child`.

Hence your issue becomes to let two unrelated components carry the same information `id`. You can create a service file to store `id`.

Answer (score 0):

try that
`this.childComponent.nativeElement.id = userId;`